# Having difficulties to prove this relation (Stokes Theorem)

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields, parametrization, stokes-theorem

Let the field, $\vec{F}$ be class $C¹$ in the open $Ω$. And $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ are
portions of regular surfaces with boundaries $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$  oriented
positively in relation to the normal $\vec{n_1}$ and $\vec{n_2}$. And such that $\operatorname{img}({\sigma_1})$ and $\operatorname{img}({\sigma_2})$
are contained in $Ω$. Suppose further that $\Gamma_1$  is obtained from $\Gamma_2$ by
a change of parameters that keeps the orientation. Prove that:

$$\int\int_{\sigma_1} \operatorname{rot}(\vec{F}) \cdot \vec{n_1}\mathrm{d}S = \int\int_{\sigma_2} \operatorname{rot}(\vec{F}) \cdot \vec{n_2}\mathrm{d}S $$

Observation:

Let $\gamma_1: [a, b]  \rightarrow \Bbb{R}^n$and $\gamma_2: [c, d]  \rightarrow \Bbb{R}^n$ both curves of class $C^1$;
suppose further that there is a function $g: [c, d] → \Bbb{R}$, of class $C^1$ with $g '(u)>0$  ; $\operatorname{dom}(g '(u))  \in ] c, d [$ and $\operatorname{img} g = [a, b]$, such that, for $\forall u \in [c, d]$. it'll conserves the orientation if: $\boldsymbol{g '(u)>0}$

Comment: Why did you wrote $dS$ twice?

Comment: I just realized it was a typo in the book, so my question was stupid. But I will consider your response, for your dedication.

Comment: Disregarding the dS factor, I think rest of the question is sound. Does my answer seem like it answers explain how to set it up correctly? @laggo Capitanio

Comment: @Buraian, yes. The exercise has become in the simple case of showing that the flow of the roacionial over any surface will depend only from the surface borders . Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

1. Use stokes to turn the surface integral of $\sigma_1$ into a line integral
2. Change coordinates in which you write the integral, such that new boundary is same of the line integral  as the one for $\sigma_2$
3. Now, since stokes is true for all surfaces attached to a given boundary. Use the $\sigma_2$ as a surface attached to the new boundary, hence the required is shown.